# Make excel worksheet mirror worksheet in external file

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

How can I make a worksheet in my excel file mirror exactly the sheet of a different (closed) worksheet.

Basically, I have around 5 files with a lot of data the gets consolidated into a single dashboard with the important information. I then want to create a file (lets call it report) that has the 'main' sheet from each of these different files.

Ideally, the report file will not have to be altered, and when it is opened it will already have all the data needed.

Note: there are merged cells in the documents that are in variable positions.

response to comment #1:

By be there already, for example you can do a vlookup referencing other workbooks.. and the values of those vlookups will be correct when you open the file. First I thought I could just say cell A1 is file 1 = cell A1 in file 2, but the merged cells throw that off because it will not create merged cells to match

Comment: How would the dashboard already contain the required information before it's even opened?  And what have you tried already, and what happened?

Comment: @TimWilliams edited with answers

Comment: If your source workbooks are formatted in such a way that you can't use formulas, then you may need to change your approach, or use VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following and it can be done in Excel VBA.
1) open consolidated workbook
2) Assuming that all the files you need to consolidate are in a given directory, you can obtain the list of all these files.
2.1) Traverse the list of files and open them one after the other
2.2) When a file is open, you might want to change the name of the sheet before moving it to the "report" file.
2.3) Close each file without saving them.